# How to Get available bytes of Windows system using C#

Tags: c#, performancecounter

I am facing one problem while retrieving available bytes of system through System.Diagnostics namespace and I tried in this bellow code.

```
PerformanceCounter pc = new PerformanceCounter("memory", "Available Bytes");
```

Even using above coding I am unable to get, if I get the available bytes for the system that is not equals to Task manager counters.

In Which way I can find solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

Rajesh

Comment: Which statistic in Task Manager are you comparing against?

Comment: It would be interesting to know why you want this information.  There are not many cases or situations where you'd want the app to do something depending on the value of this?  This perf counter I believe shows the amount of virtual memory available - are you sure that's what you want specifically?

Comment: @David: I am comparing value with Used memory graph in Task manager.

Comment: @Kieren:Actuvally we are using total 20 servers for maintaining load so, every time we need to check how much memmory avilabale and How much Memory used.But every time we have to open Task manager for every build placing insted of this we try to make one programe for showing USed and available memory.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this TechNet page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc958260.aspx) which contains tables mapping the Task Manager column names to the performance counter names.

I say this as it could be you are comparing two values which represent different aspects of memory usage: my guess is you are comparing the total memory value in TaskManager with the physical memory ('Available Bytes') performance counter.

The solution would be either to switch to the 'Committed Bytes' performance counter for total memory, or to compare the figure you are getting with the 'Physical Memory Available' value in TaskManager.